# Mockito not working for androidTest

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

i am trying to mock some objects nd then inject them to a presenter but doesnt work

It sais the lateInt property that i have a mock on is not being initialised:

Here is my test clss

```
    @Mock
    lateinit var storage: StorageContract

    @Mock
    lateinit var activityCallBack: LaunchContract.ActivityCallBack

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var launchPresenter: LaunchContract.Presenter

    @get: Rule
    @InjectMocks
    var activity: ActivityTestRule<LaunchActivity> = ActivityTestRule<LaunchActivity>(LaunchActivity::class.java)

   @Test
    fun testRegAndLoginVisible() {
        Mockito.`when`(storage.isLoggedIn()).thenReturn(false)
        onView(withId(R.id.loginBtn))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
        onView(withId(R.id.registerBtn))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

    }
```

Here is my build script

```
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'au.com.dius:pact-jvm-consumer-junit_2.11:3.5.10'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.6.3'
    testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.8.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.13.0'
```

The error i get:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property storage has not been initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have `@Mock` annotations working correctly you should:

annotate your test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)`

or

call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in your "setup" method (annotated with `@Before`)

```
@Before
fun setup() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also, make sure you are using the latest version of JDK 8, Mockito has some issues with older JDK versions (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/636)

Comment: Ok thanks that seem to at least initialise the storage object but when it tries to mock my callback class , it says moickit cannot mock this lass interfacem com.blah.LaunchContract$ActivityCallback

Comment: @jonney make sure you are using the latest version of JDK 8, as I know there are some issues with older versions (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/636)

Comment: @jonney nice to hear. I will edit the answer for future generations ;)